# Interpolation binding with double curly brackets {{ }} causing errors in attributes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have template:

```
<svg style="width:{{bWidth}}px; height:5vh;">
 <path d="M0,0 L 0, {{pathOne}} {{pathTwo}},{{pathThree}} {{pathFour}},0 Z" fill="#666666" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
 <image width="150px" height="{{imgHeight}}px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="img.png"/>
</svg>
```

I want set svg width and image height on create so,

```
app.directive("customSvg", function($document, $timeout) {
return {
  restrict: "E",
  replace: true,
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.bWidth= 150;
    scope.imgHeight=100;
    scope.pathOne = 50;
    scope.pathTwo = 50;
    scope.pathThree = 50;
    scope.pathFour = 50;
  },
  templateUrl:'template.html'
}
```

});

but in chrome console I got error:

```
angular.js:30 Error: <image> attribute height: Expected length, "{{imgHeight}}p…".
angular.js:30 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,0 L 0, {{pathOne}} {{pa…".
```

How to fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `ngAttr` for binding to arbitrary attributes

From the Docs:

> Web browsers are sometimes picky about what values they consider valid for attributes.
>
> For example, considering this template:
>
> ```
> <svg>
>   <circle cx="{{cx}}"></circle>
> </svg>
> ```
>
> We would expect AngularJS to be able to bind to this, but when we check the console we see something like `Error: Invalid value for attribute cx="{{cx}}"`. Because of the SVG DOM API's restrictions, you cannot simply write `cx="{{cx}}"`.
>
> **With `ng-attr-cx` you can work around this problem.**
>
> If an attribute with a binding is prefixed with the `ngAttr` prefix (denormalized as `ng-attr-`) then during the binding it will be applied to the corresponding unprefixed attribute. This allows you to bind to attributes that would otherwise be eagerly processed by browsers (e.g. an SVG element's `circle[cx]` attributes). When using `ngAttr`, the `allOrNothing` flag of [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) is used, so if any expression in the interpolated string results in `undefined`, the attribute is removed and not added to the element.
>
> For example, we could fix the example above by instead writing:
>
> ```
> <svg>
>   <circle ng-attr-cx="{{cx}}"></circle>
> </svg>
> ```
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation)